# Controller route attribute only relevant for root function?

Tags: c#, .net-core, routes, controller, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a question about .NET Core controller routing. Recently I discovered that the controller route attribute (which you place just above the controller) only works for the root method, or at least it seems that way.

My code:

```
using KrabbelMicroservice.Models;
using KrabbelMicroservice.Services.Interfaces;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace KrabbelMicroservice.Controllers;

[ApiController]
[Route("/profile")] // <-- This is the controller routing attribute I am talking about
public class ProfileKrabbelController : Controller
{
    private readonly IProfileKrabbelService _krabbelService;
    public ProfileKrabbelController(IProfileKrabbelService krabbelService)
    {
        _krabbelService = krabbelService;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        // not relevant
    }
    
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("/id/{krabbelId}")]
    public IActionResult GetKrabbelById(long krabbelId)
    {
        // not relevant
    }
    
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("/pid/to/{profileId}")]
    public IActionResult GetKrabbelsToProfileId(long profileId)
    {
        // not relevant
    }
    
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("/pid/from/{profileId}")]
    public IActionResult GetKrabbelsFromProfileId(long profileId)
    {
        // not relevant
    }
    
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("/pid/with/{profileId}")]
    public IActionResult GetKrabbelsWithProfileId(long profileId)
    {
        // not relevant
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("/new")]
    public IActionResult AddKrabbel(ProfileKrabbel krabbel)
    {
        // not relevant
    }
    
    [HttpPut]
    [Route("/update")]
    public IActionResult UpdateKrabbel(ProfileKrabbel krabbel)
    {
        // not relevant
    }
    
    [HttpDelete]
    [Route("/delete")]
    public IActionResult DeleteKrabbel(ProfileKrabbel krabbel)
    {
        // not relevant
    }
}
```

In my swagger launch the requests look like this:
[image]

I expected that all paths would be prefixed by /profile/ but it seems like only the root function (which did not have its own route attribute) implemented the prefix.

I am not only trying to get a fix for this, but also looking for an explanation as to why my controller route attribute is ignored for the other requests. The only possibility I can think of is the specific route attributes for each endpoint overriding the controller route attribute but I would like to hear it from an expert.

Secondly I would of course also like to find a solution to this problem, preferrably not adding /profile before every seperate route but if that is the only solution so be it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you should be remove "/" if you have root route

ex:

```
[Route("test")]
[ApiController]
public class TestController3 : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("testobj")]
    public TestObj Test()
    {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

the even shorter in httpget

```
[HttpGet("testobj")]
```

the both output:

```
test/testobj
```